# Logic to display HTML element with combination of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

Beginner newbie shyly asking for help after weeping over this with my coffee mug and Red Bull for 3-4 hours. I googled, tried different approaches from similar StackOverflow posts, but unfortunately with no luck. I hope some seasoned web developers can perhaps take a look and see what I did wrong or obviously missed. It's meant to be a helpful tool for our LARP group (magic school nerds).

**What I'd like to achieve**: User's combination of 2 choices(study year/path) displays the timetable as a HTML element below the form. Ideally without a submit button.

Here's the Codepen: https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/QRYwrY?editors=1111

For ease of debugging, only "junior" year options are included, so choosing "junior" year and "artificer" path should generate text *"Junior artificer timetable!"* within `<span id="classResult"> </span>`.

The code seems to be faulty and not generating the appropriate message for the junior year choices. Any help would be highly appreciated, as a newbie it sure has been discouraging to fall into trouble with such a seemingly simple problem..

```js
//function to run whenever user changes radio inputs
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function() {
        //making chosen radio options to variables
        var $year = $('input[name="year"]:checked');
        var $path = $('input[name="path"]:checked');
        //logic
        if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "artificer") {
          $("classResult").innerHTML = "Junior artificer timetable!";
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "cursebreaker") {
          $("classResult").innerHTML = "Junior cursebreaker timetable!";
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "crypto") {
          $("classResult").innerHTML = "Junior crypto timetable!";
        }
      });
    }
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Select your year:</p>
<input type="radio" id="junior" name="year" value="junior">Junior
<br>
<input type="radio" id="sophomore" name="year" value="sophomore">Sophomore
<br>
<input type="radio" id="senior" name="year" value="senior">Senior
<br>
<p>Select your path:</p>
<input type="radio" id="artificer" name="path" value="artificer">Artificer
<br>
<input type="radio" id="cursebreaker" name="path" value="cursebreaker">Curse Breaker
<br>
<input type="radio" id="crypto" name="path" value="crypto">Cryptozoologist
<br>

<span id="classResult"> </span>

<br />
<br />

<!--jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your code is not complete  - I made you a snippet. Fix the missing brackets

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBPvyQ?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has two errors:
The method call to `ready` is not closed correctly.
You also have to set the html content using `.html()` and you have to select by id using `#id`. The following code should be correct:

```
//function to run whenever user changes radio inputs
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
        //making chosen radio options to variables
        var $year = $('input[name="year"]:checked');
        var $path = $('input[name="path"]:checked');
        //logic
        if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "artificer") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior artificer timetable!");
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "cursebreaker") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior cursebreaker timetable!");
        } else if ($year.val() == "junior" && $path.val() == "crypto") {
            $("#classResult").html("Junior crypto timetable!");
        }
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/lukasmoeller/pen/KLJpBg?editors=1111

Comment: I can not express my gratitude well enough - thank you! In another project I used innerHTML method, so I guess that's why it felt right here too. Any idea how tricky it would be to achieve the same thing via button clicks instead of radio inputs? (just realised maybe visually it would be more user-friendly)

Comment: If you want to achieve the same with buttons you could do it like this, however this is not very clean: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lukasmoeller/pen/KLJpBg?editors=1111). I personally would prefer using radio inputs like you did as they are made for this purpose - selecting one of many choices.